# Как правильно использовать "this" в операторе?

Tags: c++

У меня следующий код:

```
class Complex {
 private:
    double re, im;
 public:
    Complex (double re) {
       this->re = re;
       this->im = 0;
    };
    Complex operator+ (Complex c);
    Complex operator+ (double d);        
};
Complex Complex::operator+ (Complex c) {
    Complex cc(c.re + re, c.im + im);
    return cc; 
};

Complex Complex::operator+ (double d) {
    Complex c(d);
    return (c+this*);  
};
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
expected expression
return (c+this*);
```

Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас объявлен конструктор с одним параметром

```
Complex (double re) {
   this->re = re;
   this->im = 0;
};
```

Однако в этом операторе вы пытаетесь вызвать конструктор с двумя аргументами

```
Complex Complex::operator+ (Complex c) {
    Complex cc(c.re + re, c.im + im);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
    return cc; 
};
```

Очевидно необходимо также объявить конструктор с двумя параметрами.

Эти операторы

```
Complex operator+ (Complex c);
Complex operator+ (double d);
```

лучше объявить следующим образом

```
Complex operator +( const Complex &c ) const;
Complex operator +( double d ) const;
```

так как 1) объекты, которые складываются, сами не изменяются (поэтому добавлен квалификатор `const` после списка параметров); и 2) параметр типа `Complex`  желательно передавать по константной ссылке, чтобы избежать ненужного создагния и копирования временных объектов.

Данная конструкция

```
return (c+this*);
```

синтаксически неверная.

Определение класса может выглядеть следующим образом, как это показано в демонстрационной программе ниже.

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex 
{
private:
    double re, im;

public:
    explicit Complex ( double re = 0.0, double im = 0.0 ) 
    {
        this->re = re;
        this->im = im;
    }

    Complex operator +( const Complex &c ) const;
    Complex operator +( double d ) const;

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Complex &c )
    {
        return os << "{ " << c.re << ", " << c.im << " }";
    }
};

Complex Complex::operator +( const Complex &c ) const
{
    return Complex( this->re + c.re, this->im + c.im );
}

Complex Complex::operator +( double d ) const 
{
    return Complex( this->re + d, this->im + d );
}

int main() 
{
    Complex c1( 10, 10 );

    std::cout << "c1 = " << c1 << std::endl;

    Complex c2 = c1 + 5;

    std::cout << "c2 = " << c2 << std::endl;

    Complex c3 = c1 + c2;

    std::cout << "c3 = " << c3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
c1 = { 10, 10 }
c2 = { 15, 15 }
c3 = { 25, 25 }
```

Или оператор `operator +( double ) const` на ваше усмотрение может быть определен как

```
Complex Complex::operator +( double d ) const 
{
    return Complex( this->re + d, this->im );
}
```

Что касается использования `this` в возвращаемом выражении из операторов, то в этих операторах, которые у вас объявлены, большого смысла использовать `this` нет.

Но вы могли бы определить операторы `operator +=`, то есть составной оператор присваивания. Они могут выглядеть следующим образом

```
Complex & operator +=( const Complex &c )
{
    this->re += c.re;
    this->im += c.im;

    return *this;
}

Complex & operator +=( double d )
{
    this->re += d;
    this->im += d;

    return *this;
}
```

или

```
Complex & operator +=( double d )
{
    this->re += d;

    return *this;
}
```

Здесь в возвращаемых значениях из операторов используется указатель на объекты `this`.

Другая возможность использовать `this` - это определить оператор `operator +( double ) const` через оператор `operator +( const Complex & ) const`. В этом случае определение оператора `operator +( double ) const` можкт выглядеть следующим образом

```
Complex Complex::operator +( double d ) const 
{
    return *this + Complex( d, d );
//  return Complex( this->re + d, this->im + d );
}
```

или

```
Complex Complex::operator +( double d ) const 
{
    return *this + Complex( d );
//  return Complex( this->re + d, this->im );
}
```

Comment: А разве прибавление `double` к `Complex` должно изменять мнимую часть числа?

Comment: @PetSerAl Это как вы сами решите. Оба подхода выглядят логично.

Comment: В математике обычно действительное число `d` ассоциируют с комплексным числом `(d, 0)`, поэтому математики ожидали бы от сложения `d + (re, im)` такой же результат, как и от сложения `(d, 0) + (re, im)`.

Comment: @VladD В данном вопросе обсуждается не математика, а как корректно с точки зрения языка C++ написать операторы, как их объявить, и что возвращать из них. Внутрь тела операторов вы можете поместить любые вычисления, которые считаете нужными.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Я понимаю это, конечно. Поэтому у меня в комментарии сослагательное наклонение.

Answer (score 1):

Звёздочка для разыменования `this` ставится с другой стороны:

```
Complex Complex::operator+ (double d) {
    Complex c(d);
    return (c + *this);  
}
```

---

Кстати, в вашем коде не хватает конструктора с двумя `double`-параметрами:

```
Complex (double re, double im) : re(re), im(im) { }
```

А конструктор с одним параметром обычно записывают тоже в упрощённом виде:

```
Complex (double re) : re(re), im(0) { }
```

Comment: А что в этом виде "упрощенного"?

Comment: @AnT: отсутствует `=` и `this`?

Comment: @AnT: Да, я знаю, что вызов конструктора и присваивание это, формально говоря, не одно и то же. Но я не хочу запутывать ТС, всё же уровень задания достаточно новичковый.

Answer (score 1):

Оператор разыменования указателя в языке С++ - это *унарный* оператор. И как всякий унарный оператор, он указывается *перед* своим операндом, а не после него: `*this`.

Вообще говоря, если ваш конструктор из типа `double` не является `explicit`, то писать отдельный оператор для типа `double`

```
Complex operator+ (double d);
```

формально нет никакой необходимости. Компилятор автоматически проинтерпретирует выражение `Complex + double` как `Complex + Complex(double)`, т.е. воспользуется уже существующим оператором `+`.

Однако стоить заметить, что такие операторы `+`, реализованные через функции-члены класса, должны быть объявлены `const`

```
Complex operator+ (Complex c) const;
```

и передачу параметра, возможно, лучше сделать по константной ссылке.

А также стоит заметить, что реализовывать эти операторы надо было бы отдельностоящими функциями, а не функции-членами класса. Из-за того, что вы сделали эти функции членами класса, выражения `Complex + double` у вас поддерживаются, а `double + Complex` - нет.